# Good WPF or silverlight windows gadget examples

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-desktop-gadgets

Does anyone have a good example of a WPF or silverlight windows gadget?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

norlando02,

Hello, I've come across a few sidebar gadget demos and tutorials online.  I'll list them here for your review.  Hopefully some of them catch your eye, and help you in your endeavorers.

### WPF:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/3d-gadget-WPF.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFGadget.aspx
- Part 1: http://blogs.msdn.com/karstenj/default.aspx
- Part 2: http://blogs.msdn.com/karstenj/archive/2006/10/09/activex-wpf-gadget.aspx
- <strike>This one was removed from the source site, but it still has some nice (cached) information: 
  http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:2G8BDYIxUnMJ:www.stoyanoff.info/code/wss/A%2520Guide%2520to%2520Writing%2520WPF%2520Gadgets.pdf+A+Guide+to+Developing+Windows+Presentation+Foundation+Gadgets+for+Windows+Sidebar&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiddo987Inzj03id5U2_bYiYiIvdoRbI9H6R74GF7BXFTJHVDwrxYexKwLQprAsHELSA6EG3aQKdfgii0Q2EqkOJwzk2_qa2n1pAdweTRRt4mTE1n4-LDhdpRnbvRCmjSA5Dvkt&sig=AHIEtbRvXs8b4Z5iUYwIds1yQhkg-1L-mw</strike> (No longer cached)

### Silverlight:

- http://www.lazarciuc.ro/ioan/2008/08/02/creating-a-vista-sidebar-gadget-using-microsoft-silverlight/
- http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/05/vista-sidebar-gadget-using-silverlight.html
- Stack Overflow: [Silverlight 2 Sidebar Gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/silverlight-2-sidebar-gadget)
- Detailed Video: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles_Sterling/Building-a-Windows-Side-Bar-gadget-for-tracking-traffic/

I hope thses references help,

### Thanks!