# How to make a winform open like Mac OS animation?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

Could any one tell how can I open a form with an animation similar to the one used by Mac-OS launcher. I have seen a few other software doing the same thing. For eg: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4uhOEYzl30) youtube video also shows a demo of it (@Time: 20 sec and @Time: 28 sec).

I know of `animateWindow` API, but I think this is not possible with `animateWindow`.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AnimateWindow won't fit the bill.

In my opinion these programs work by

- Creating a transparent window when needed, while computing icons to display
- Creating the animation and displaying it on the transparent window device context
- Handling **everything** on the window via custom events.

What you need is

- a comprehensive knowledge of GDI32
- an equally comprehensive knowledge of those dirty tricks used to create animations programmatically.

I'm sorry, but I think that this is not the kind of topic that can briefly explained on a single answer :-(

Eventually, you need something that augments and extends Windows's native graphic capabilities. There are companies that did this before: IIRC Serif.com did write their own GDI replacement for their DTP programs, and I think that all of these companies that make desktop enhancements did the same (or at least, they **know** how to squeeze GDI32 capabilities)

Comment: Although not the perfect answer I'd expected, but pointing to GDI32 was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try WPF or SilverLight or mixure of above to meet your requirements.

You can check [Good WPF or silverlight windows gadget examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770909/good-wpf-or-silverlight-windows-gadget-examples) and let me know.