# I need a UI Control for .net windows forms application

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

I need a UI control for a windows forms application. I don't know what the name of such UI is but I can describe what I want: I can to have a button on my form that when I hover the mouse over it, the CONTROL which I am looking for gets opened beside my form with animation and I want to add some buttons in that control. What is that control? Is there any such control in RAD Controls which I can use? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is another `Form` with some customization (Perhaps removing the control box on top e.g. close, maximize and minimize). And you can open this form in your buttons `MouseHover` event.
Something like:

```
private void MyButton_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Assume that you made this form in designer
var cutomForm = new CustomForm(); 
//Set the opening location somewhere on the right side of main form, you can change it ofc
cutomForm.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width, this.Height / 2);
//Probably topmost is needed
cutromForm.TopMust = true;
customForm.Show();
}
```

As for animation, you can search for animation for winformws on google.Or look here and there, something like : [WinForms animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503173/how-to-make-a-winform-open-like-mac-os-animation)

**Regarding your other question**

If you want the new opened form to move with your move, then you need some changes. First you need to have the new form as a field in your code (then the button hover also should be changed):

```
    private CustomForm _customForm;

     private void MyButton_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Check if customForm was perviously opened or not
      if(_customForm != null)
          return;

      //Assume that you made this form in designer
      _customForm= new CustomForm(); 
      //Set the opening location somewhere on the right side of main form, you can change it ofc
      _customForm.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width, this.Height / 2);
      //Probably topmost is needed
      _customForm.TopMust = true; 

      //Delegate to make form null on close
      _customForm.FormClosed += delegate { _customForm = null;};   
      _customForm.Show();
    }
```

For keep both form moving together, you need to handle that in the `Move` event of your main form, something like:

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         if(_customForm != null)
         {
          //Not sure if this gonna work as you want but you got the idea I guess
          _customForm.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width, this.Height / 2);

         }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your good answer , and I want the opening form to stick to it's parent's top right corner , what can i do to achieve that ? I mean even when the parent is moving I want the opened form to stick to the parent

Comment: @Karamafrooz mokhlesim.